# XmppFramework I'm getting KissXml error

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm getting this error `Module 'KissXml' not found` on XMPPFramework I couldn't solve this problem please help me! I setup XmppFramework like Github my Xcode version is 7.2

[image]

Comment: Did you get any answer ? Having same issue.

Comment: No I didnt, but I'm tried with cocoapods and it works so for now im working with pod but my main error still not fix

Comment: yepp same here ... using pods now :P

Comment: it working fine when using it through pod but same issue while clone using github...pls help!

Comment: I think you should use through pod forget the clone like me :)

Comment: @CenkIşık did you get any answer ?

Comment: @Mani I solved with cocoa pods I didnt setup manually. Add this line to your podfile "pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.6' " and it will work.

Comment: @CenkIşık Thanks. I'll try that

Answer (score 2):

I use CocoaPods at the beginning, but because of the need to modify the source code to meet certain requirements, so manually add XMPPFramework, but encountered all sorts of mistakes. One blogger noted, but I have solved the problem.

By replace

```
@import KissXml;
```

to

```
#import "DDXML.h"
```

Have a  try~

Answer (score 1):

If you change your @import KissXML to #import "KissXML.h" and @import CocoaAsyncSocket to #import "CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h". Your problem should be solved.